# Omtex mobile version account/login error

Tags: php, opencart

I installed omtex extension on my website but when I try to access account or try to register it brings a fatal error:

> call to a member function modcheck() on a non object in vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php line 91

Here is the code:

```php
            // LINE 80 HERE BELOW
            ob_start();

            require(VQMod::modCheck(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->template)));

            $this->output = ob_get_contents();

            ob_end_clean();

            return $this->output;
        } else {
            // LINE 91 HERE BELOW
            $file_default = $vqmod->modCheck(DIR_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE . $this->template);
            if (file_exists($file_default)) {
            extract($this->data);
            ob_start();
            require(VQMod::modCheck(VQMod::modCheck($file_default)));
            $this->output = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $this->output;
        }
```

Comment: `$vqmod` isn't defined in your render() function where you're trying to use it.

Comment: Did you try to delete the contents of `vqmod/vqcache/` folder? Did you try to disable that omtex extension, delete the contents of `vqmod/vqcache/` folder? If not, try it. If the site works properly with the omtex disabled then contact the extension developer for support.

Comment: @shadyyx , it works well on the desktop side but when i try acessing using mobile, i get that error. Omtex has the worst customer support,

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it statically here:

```
    require(VQMod::modCheck(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->template)));
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

and various other places, but as a method here:

```
    $file_default = $vqmod->modCheck(DIR_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE . $this->template);
```

and in a couple places. is `$vqmod` an object? Your error suggests it's not.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it doesnt solve my issue. probably one who has installed and used omtex should help, i can give you access to my files.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `vQmod` is not instance based - it's static. This change occurred over a year ago, and as such the code above should be upgraded. Simply changing `$vqmod->modCheck` to `VQMod::modCheck` will solve this issue. Also, if there is a `global $vqmod;` somewhere before the outdated code, remove it. You should also check your installation, as there should not be two calls to `VQMod::modCheck` in the requires. Either you've got two XML files doing the same thing, or you've hard coded the modCheck for whatever reason

Comment: I have tried that , but am still getting an error. probably i should give you access to my files and you see what could be wrong with omtex extension

Comment: @TayebwaEnock - You should contact Omtex or hire a developer to debug and fix this

Comment: omtex have the worst client support, they dont respond to queries sent to them,

Comment: Then you'll need to contact a developer to apply the changes. This isn't a free work community. If you don't know how to apply the fixes people have given you need to hire someone that does